# What's the meaning of the field strmap in the struct load_info?

Tags: linux, kernel, dynamic-linking, module

I'm studying the mechanism of module loading inside the linux kernel, and I'm stuck at the meaning of the field `strmap` inside the struct `load_info`.

The struct is defined [in `kernel/module.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.39/kernel/module.c#L135) and the field is filled [in `kernel/module.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.39/kernel/module.c#L2128). I know it is a bitmap, but I can't figure out the meaning of the individual bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I couldn't find anything on LWN. This is a partial analysis of the code. Note that `strmap` existed as a separate variable before `struct load_info` was introduced.)*

`strtab` contains a bunch of null-terminated strings concatenated together. E.g. it might contain this, where `.` stands for a null character:

```
foo.bar.quux.corge.
0123456789012345678
```

In [`layout_symtab`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/kernel/module.c#L2113), `strmap` is used to determine which chunks of `strtab` correspond to [core symbols](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/kernel/module.c#L2092). The [loop](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/kernel/module.c#L2128) sets the jth bit of `strtab` whenever the jth character is part of the name of a core symbol. For example, given the table above, if `bar` and `corge` are core symbols then bits 4–7 and 13–18 are set to 1.

In [`add_kallsyms`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/kernel/module.c#L2154), the [second loop](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/kernel/module.c#L2174) computes the total length of the names of the core symbols, and the [third loop](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/kernel/module.c#L2185) copies the core symbols into a new table `mod->symtab` by copying only the bytes of `strtab` for which the corresponding bit in `strmap` is set. In the example above, the new table would contain `bar.corge.`.